# How to include C library <sys/mman_peer.h>

Tags: c, include, mmap

I am trying to include the library i found there https://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/7.0.0/#com.qnx.doc.neutrino.lib_ref/topic/m/mmap_peer.html
I did not found a lot of informations about mman_peer. When i trying to inlude the library, gcc compiler throws me an error. What is the possible problem?

Comment: This is a nonstandard header. I would expect it only to be available on QNX. Was that the operating system you were compiling for? (If not, why were you consulting QNX-specific documentation?)

Comment: i am using linux ubuntu...i didnt know that QNX is an operating system, thats the problem :) so, it is impossible then

Comment: I can tell you for sure that this API is _not_ available on Linux.  What did you want `mmap_peer` for?  There may be a better way to get that done.

Answer (score 2):

`mmap_peer` is a nonstandard QNX function. Linux doesn't have it. To map memory in another process's address space on Linux, you need to instead `ptrace` the target process and force it to execute the `mmap` syscall itself. That's what GDB does if you do something like this: `gdb -ex 'call mmap(0, 4096, 3, 33, -1, 0)' --pid=12345 --batch`

If you wanted to do from your own program what GDB is doing there, you'd need to use architecture-specific APIs, which I can't show you since you didn't mention an architecture in your question.

Comment: I'm trying to do code injection, but the problem is, that the new function could be larger than existed func. So i want to allocate a new page with mmap, insert there a new functiion with ptrace and then change start of old function with  jmp instruction (to start of new function). If you answer some of questions it will help much. Am i need first to insert mmap call to target process? If i leave first argument of mmap as 0, is it return me free page, or i shoul manualy find the free virtual address? Also there is option of share memory page with mmap (MAP_SHARED), what do you think about it?